# Capistrano - Rename after Deploy

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, capistrano3

We're just getting up to speed on Capistrano and I could use some help.  We're running codeIgniter and would like to allow our devs to run/test locally, push to the Git repo when we've got a complete module.  The issue is that in order to run locally, you need to set up the environment to look for the system as well as the models, views and controllers.

Rather than write a bunch of conditional code into index.php that could get munged accidentally or some such, I'd rather have a static file called "index-server.php" and use Capistrano to rename index-server.php to index.php after a deployment is complete.

I'm not even sure what this would look like but I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: Is your question specifically about renaming a file after deployment, or are you just trying to make sure that your index.php file isn't accessible until the deployment is complete?

Comment: The issue is that I want the devs to be able to modify the local copy of index.php at will to match their local environment as they see fit.  But when it gets deployed from the repo, I want the index.php that matches the server configuration to be put into place.  Everyone will know not to mess with "index-server.php" that will be at the webroot--but it will be available for reference, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly new to capistrano as well, but I did manage to execute system commands on the deploy target by adding this to deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:app), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      execute "/bin/mv #{File.join(release_path, 'index-server.php')} #{File.join(release_path, 'index.php')}"
    end
  end

end
```

Or something along those lines. Hope it helps!

*Edit: this is with Capistrano 3*